# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' OK

Tags: opencart

помогите разобраться, при оформлении заказа появляется вот такое ругательство:

SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
OK
**Notice**: Undefined index: products in **/var/www/u0522611/data/www/ххх/catalog/controller/extension/module/notificationTelegram.php** on line **105****Notice**: Undefined index: products in **/var/www/u0522611/data/www/ххх/catalog/controller/extension/module/notificationTelegram.php** on line **105****Notice**: Undefined index: products in **/var/www/u0522611/data/www/ххх/catalog/controller/extension/module/notificationTelegram.php** on line **105**{"redirect":"http://ххх/index.php?route=checkout/success"}

код:

```
public function sendOrderAlert(&$route, &$data, &$output) {

    $order_id = $data[0];
    $this->load->model('checkout/order');
    $order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($order_id);

    $this->load->model('setting/setting');
    $setting = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('module_notificationTelegram');

    if (isset($setting['module_notificationTelegram_order_alert'])) {

        $this->load->model('account/order');
        if (count($this->model_account_order->getOrderHistories($order_id)) <= 1) {
            $message = $this->replaceMessage($setting['module_notificationTelegram_meassage'],$order_info);
```

//                  $message .= $this->buldArray($order_info);

```
            $this->sendMessagetoTelegam($message);

            if (strpos(strtolower($setting['module_notificationTelegram_meassage']), '{products}') !== false) {
                $order_products = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrderProducts($order_id);
                $products = $this->bulidProducts($order_products);
                $this->sendMessagetoTelegam($products);

            }
        }

    }

}

public function sendAccountAlert(&$route, &$data, &$output) {
    $this->load->model('setting/setting');
    $setting = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('module_notificationTelegram');
    if (isset($setting['module_notificationTelegram_customer_alert'])) {

        $message = $this->replaceMessage($setting['module_notificationTelegram_new_account_meassage'],$data[0]);
        $this->sendMessagetoTelegam( $message);

    }
}

public function sendReturnProductAlert(&$data,&$output) {
    $this->load->model('setting/setting');
    $setting = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('module_notificationTelegram');
    if (isset($setting['module_notificationTelegram_return_alert'])) {

        $message = "Return request \n ";
        $this->sendMessagetoTelegam( $message);
    }
}


//Send  message To notificationTelegram
public function sendMessagetoTelegam($msg) {

    $this->load->model('setting/setting');
    $setting = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('module_notificationTelegram');

    //print_r($setting);
    $botToken = $setting['module_notificationTelegram_boot_token'];
    $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $botToken;
    $chatIds = $setting['module_notificationTelegram_chat_ids'];  //Receiver Chat Id

    if (is_array($chatIds)) {
        foreach ($chatIds as $val) {
            $this->initMessage($botToken, $val, $msg);
        }
    } else {
        $this->initMessage($botToken, $chatIds, $msg);
    }
}
private function initMessage($botToken, $chatID, $msg) {

    $website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $botToken;

    $params = [
        'chat_id' => $chatID,
        'text' => $msg,
    ];
    $ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);            
}

public function buldArray($arr) {
    if (is_array($arr)) {
        $dataAttributes = array_map(function ($value, $key) {
            return @"$key ---> $value  \n";
        }, array_values($arr), array_keys($arr));

        return $dataAttributes = implode(' ', $dataAttributes);
    }
}

public function replaceMessage($string,$arr) {
    return   $str = preg_replace_callback('/{(\w+)}/', function($match) use($arr) {
        return $arr[$match[1]];
    }, $string );

}

protected function  bulidProducts($products){

    $pr = array();

    foreach ($products as $product){
        $pr[] = "Name : $product[name]  \n    Price: $product[price] \n qty : $product[quantity] ";
    }

    return implode("------- \n",$pr);

}
```

}

Comment: это какой-то сторонний модуль, который после оформления заказа отправляет уведомление на телегу?

Comment: да, но я уже потеряла надежду довести его до ума, никто ничего не подсказал

Comment: очень в общем: ваш модуль пытается получить данные заказа, но их нет (они ему не передаются)